# Where is Nancy's CancellationToken for async Request Handlers coming from and when is it cancelled?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, async-await, nancy

This is more a question regarding understanding how and when Nancy might cancel an async request handler via the provided cancellationToken instance.

Basically what I am wondering about is in what conditions is the token's .IsCancellationRequested set to true - is this documented or explained somewhere?

How does Nancy handle async handlers that 'never' return / in 'time'?  And regarding 'in time': is there a timeout / limit after which handlers do get cancelled?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question but I was in your same situation and I think I found an answer at least if you are using Owin to host your app (using `Nancy.Owin`).

The `CancellationToken` comes directly from Owin via the `IOwinRequest.CallCancelled` property ([Nancy source code](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/master/src/Nancy/Owin/NancyMiddleware.cs#L69) and [used here](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/master/src/Nancy/Owin/NancyMiddleware.cs#L98)). This token can be set by Owin if the request is cancelled (for example by forcibly closing the HTTP connection).

Answer (score 1):

Every CancellationToken comes from somewhere, and that somewhere is its CancellationTokenSource.

When you call CancellationTokenSource.Cancel, every token created from it is flagged.

---

Fun fact: CancellationToken is a struct, which means every time you pass it to a function or assign it to a variable it makes a new copy. Since the source can't keep track of all of those copies, we can't have a CancellationToken.IWasCancelled event. Instead, when you call IsCancellationRequested, the token has to asks its source.

ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource(v=vs.110).aspx

---

So going back to Nancy, search their source code for CancellationTokenSource and you'll find your answer. Here's the only one I saw.

https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/8a29b0495bfac4806536327c4d78de1ee59bd513/src/Nancy/NancyEngine.cs

Answer (score -1):

That's the beauty of cancellation tokens, *you don't have to know or care how they get set*.  That's entirely up to the person providing you the token.  You just get to look at the token and see whether or not it's been set.

If you're calling a method that accepts a `CancellationToken` and you want to know how to create one that you can set whenever you want, then you should be using a `CancellationTokenSource` to create a token; you can use the CTS to cancel the token that it generates, or set it to be cancelled after a set period of time.

Comment: that's all fine - the code itself does not care about the when and how - it cancels when and as requested as quickly as possible. As I said, it is me who wants to understand how and when Nancy does it.

Comment: @JörgB. You *can't*.  It's *intentionally obscured from you* to know the specific mechanism of how the caller intends to go about cancelling the cancellation token.  How *could* you possibly know?  The only things you can do are what's provided in the API of the token, namely to determine if it is currently canceled or to register an event handler to be fired when it's cancelled.  That's it.  If you want something else you'll need to create your own mechanism for it.

Comment: thanks but you are missing the question I've asked - I am not talking or wondering about the general concept of CancellationTokens. As I said, that's well understood. I am curious about Nancy. And its async handlers. This is turning in a wrong, odd direction. I (the person, not my code) am interested in Nancy and its async handlers' mechanics. If someone knows and says it is forwarded 1:1 from Asp.Net.. I'm happy. If there's more, I'm interested in that.