# Testing cancellation-handling code in an async Nancy route?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, nancy

When testing an asynchronous route in Nancy, how would I simulate a cancellation condition in my unit test?

In looking at this [question on the source of Nancy's cancellation tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30675061/48700), it wasn't really established how a cancellation could be triggered. Knowing that could possibly help here, but even without that knowledge, is there some method on `Browser` or `Browser.Get` for forcing `IsCancellationRequested` to be true on the provided async cancellation token?

Here's a very simplified async route where I have a cancellation path and the incomplete test I'm hoping to target that cancellation logic.

```
Get["/somethingasync", runAsync: true] = async (parameters, cancellationToken) => {
    await DoSomethingSlow();
    // Check for cancellation before doing anything else slow
    if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) {
        // TODO: How do I force this path to be taken in a test?
        return "cancelled";
    }
    await DoSomethingElseSlow();
    return "success";
};

[Test]
public void Cancelled_request_should_return_cancelled ()
{
    // Given
    var browser = new Browser (with => {
        with.Module<SomeModuleContainingAboveRoute> ();
    });

    // TODO: What goes here to make the following `Get` take the
    //       cancellation path in the above route?

    // When
    var result = browser.Get ("/somethingasync", with => {
        with.HttpRequest ();
    });

    // Then
    Assert.AreEqual ("cancelled", result.Body.AsString ());
}
```